# Updating of TAI

Tags: planetary-science, interplanetary, time, stars

In spaceflight keeping track of time between systems widely separated in space (e.g. people on Earth vs spacecraft in deep space) and/or time, moving at substantial relative velocities and in different gravitational potentials is a challenge.

The documentation for JPL's Horizons at https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons_doc includes the following discussion of timescales.

> The three time systems are described as follows:
>
> TDB
>
> ("Barycentric Dynamical Time"); typically for cartesian, osculating element, and close-approach tables. The uniform time scale and independent variable of the planetary ephemeris dynamical equations of motion.
>
> TT
>
> ("Terrestrial (Dynamic) Time"), called TDT prior to 1991, used for observer quantity tables. **This is proper time as measured by an Earth-bound observer and is directly related to atomic time, TAI.** TT periodically differs from TDB by, at most, 0.002 seconds.
>
> UT
>
> is Universal Time This can mean one of two non-uniform time-scales based on the rotation of the Earth. For this program, prior to 1962, UT means UT1. After 1962, UT means UTC or "Coordinated Universal Time". Future UTC leap-seconds are not known yet, so the closest known leap-second correction is used over future time-spans.

---

Different time scales are managed differently, and some are updated and/or corrected relative to others *from time to time* (pun intended).

**Question:** When and for what purpose is TAI updated?  (not about a one-second error)

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  Are you asking about international atomic time?  What does this question have to do with space, or with the tags you have labelled this question?

Comment: @DrSheldon It seems user37920 is worried that if they add the context they will be shot down for asking multiple questions in one post. Here is the context they provided: "what [do] the [astronauts] feel and experience when TAI is updated? And what is the minimum or maximum TAI allowed to be updated?"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is **off-topic**.  International Atomic Time (TAI) is a physics subject, and runs continuously without corrections.  Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) is an astronomy subject, and corrects for the motion of the Earth.  Both systems are maintained from the Earth's surface, without the involvement of satellites, astronauts, or space agencies.

Comment: @DrSheldon - An accurate concept of time is essential for accurately modeling the motion of a satellite orbiting the Earth or of a probe sent from the Earth to somewhere else in the solar system. Accurate timekeeping is essential for space exploration. I'll vote to reopen if this question is closed as off-topic.

Comment: @DrSheldon before voting to deny anybody and everybody the opportunity to post an answer to the question, [just type "TAI" in the search bar for this site](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22TAI%22) and see what comes up. Also [check Astronomy SE similarly](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22TAI%22)

Comment: @DrSheldon That this question is on-topic at physics.SE, astronomy.SE, and possibly others, does not mean that it is off-topic here. There are overlaps between different elements of the Stack Exchange network, and that is okay.

Comment: @uhoh: Completely irrelevant argument.  There are questions here about food, yet that does not make *every* question about food on-topic.  TAI (and UTC) would still exist even if rockets and satellites were never invented.  The subject is off-topic.

Comment: @DrSheldon 1) advantage of having this kind of question asked and answered here is that subsequent questions about TAI can point to it and readers *of this site* can draw from it. 2) Even if the question feel intolerable, why not give the OP at least a day to to respond and add something to address your comment, or you or someone else to edit it? The insta-close primarily punishes the rest of the community by denying some of them an opportunity to post an answer and denying the rest of us the opportunity to read those answers.

Comment: @DrSheldon I don't see any fire here that needs putting out; a 6 question per day site doesn't need to operate in triage mode.

Comment: absolutely not related in any way, but not puzzlingly it keeps coming up in searches: [TAI Delivers More Spaceflight Model Graphite Fiber Thermal Straps (GFTS) to NASA's IXPE Mission](https://www.techapps.com/blog/tai-delivers-more-spaceflight-model-graphite-fiber-thermal-straps-gfts-to-nasas-ixpe-mission)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TAI conceptually is time measured by a perfect atomic clock running exactly at the geoid. There are some issues with this concept:

- A perfect atomic clock does not exist.
- Older and presumably less accurate atomic clocks are regularly replaced with newer and presumably more accurate atomic clocks.
- Few, if any, atomic clocks are at sea level.
- Mean sea level is close to but not the same as the geoid.
- The geoid is not perfectly known.

This means that the averaging and scaling used to combine atomic clock outputs to generate TAI needs to be updated as older, less accurate atomic clocks are replaced with newer, more accurate atomic clocks, and as knowledge of the geoid improves.

That said, errors made in the TAI timestamps of past events due to imperfect clocks remain errors forever. TAI is not updated retroactively.

Comment: What is the rationale for the downvote?

Comment: I wrote a similar question on a post of my own once, and somebody replied "This is Stack Exchange, *there's always* a down vote." Of course here in space perhaps it was a cosmic ray-induced bit flip. :-)

Comment: @DavidHammen  I *semi-sure* TAI is never amended after the event (can't find a definitive statement on the BIPM site but [Steve Allen's timescales page](https://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/timescales.html#TAI) which is trustworthy says so). The clock weights and frequency of TAI are measured and adjusted but predict for the future. There is a post-processed version called `TT(BIPM)` which appears later which is a "better TAI" and changes to TAI's corrections have [happened before](https://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/dutc.html#TAI)

Comment: @astrosnapper While TAI is not amended after the fact, how the scale factors and weights by which the different atomic clocks that collectively form TAI are updated for current and future determination of TAI.

Comment: Agreed, and this is probably pedantry, but the last sentence of the answer could be read as past TAI times can be amended retroactively. This doesn't happen, even when problems become known such as the lack of gravitational redshift (time slowing with altitude/distance from the geoid) correction before 1977. Also note for OP/others: TAI is not distributed (only UTC is) and "true" TAI and UTC are only available after 10-40 days following the comparisons, weight adjustment and publication of [Circular T](https://www.bipm.org/en/bipm-services/timescales/time-ftp/Circular-T.html). Time is weird...

Comment: I've updated the question to add more context to address topicality issues. Other than context, I don't think the edits affect your answer, but if you have a chance, have a look just in case.

Comment: @astrosnapper to your final sentence, agreed, and to the name "circular T", how apropos!